# Converting 32 bit OleAut call into 64 bit in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, ole-automation

I'm having some problems with converting this API call into 64 bit accessible call from VBA.

### API declaration

```vb
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DispCallFunc Lib "OleAut32.dll" ( _
    ByVal pvInstance As Long, _
    ByVal oVft As Long, _
    ByVal cc As Long, _
    ByVal vtReturn As Integer, _
    ByVal cActuals As Long, _
    ByVal prgvt As Long, _
    ByVal prgpvarg As Long, _
    ByVal pvargResult As Long _
    ) As Long
```

### Client code

```vb
Public Sub Main()

    ' On this line I get "compile error: type mismatch" because AddressOf method
    ' returns LongPtr but DispCallFunc expects Long.
    DispCallFunc 0, AddressOf Foo, CLng(4), VbVarType.vbEmpty, 0, 0, 0, 0

End Sub


Private Sub Foo()
    Debug.Print 100
End Sub
```

---

I tried to change `Long` to `LongPtr` in `DispCallFunc` but every time I make that change to the API and run macro, Excel freezes.

Comment: The declaration looks funny even in 32-bit. Anyway, can you test this (I can't): `Private Declare PtrSafe Function DispCallFunc Lib "OleAut32.dll" (ByVal pvInstance As LongPtr, ByVal oVft As LongPtr, ByVal cc As Integer, ByVal vtReturn As Integer, ByVal cActuals As Long, ByRef prgvt As Integer, ByRef prgpvarg As LongPtr, ByRef pvargResult  As Variant) As Long`

Comment: It worked! Can you post this piece of code with the explanation why it works, so I can give you some sweet virtual points? :)

Comment: Added an answer, with few adjustments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DispCallFunc function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-dispcallfunc) is declared like this:

```
HRESULT DispCallFunc(
  void       *pvInstance,
  ULONG_PTR  oVft,
  CALLCONV   cc,
  VARTYPE    vtReturn,
  UINT       cActuals,
  VARTYPE    *prgvt,
  VARIANTARG **prgpvarg,
  VARIANT    *pvargResult
);
```

- pvInstance is a pointer [input]
- oVft is a pointer [input]
- cc is a 32-bit integer [input]
- vtReturn is a 16-bit integer [input]
- cActuals is a 32-bit integer [input]
- prgvt is an array of 16-bit integers (so a pointer) [input]
- prgpvarg is an array of pointer on VARIANTs (so a pointer) [input]
- pvargResult is a pointer on a VARIANT, so a byref VBA's Variant [output]

So, for VBA:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DispCallFunc Lib "OleAut32.dll" ( _
    ByVal pvInstance As LongPtr, _
    ByVal oVft As LongPtr, _
    ByVal cc As Long, _
    ByVal vtReturn As Integer, _
    ByVal cActuals As Long, _
    ByVal prgvt As LongPtr, _
    ByVal prgpvarg As LongPtr, _
    ByRef pvargResult As Variant) As Long
```

Comment: In addition, the parameters 7 & 8 can be declared as `ByRef prgvt As Integer` and `ByRef prgpvarg As LongPtr` respectively, then rather than pass `VarPtr(theArray(0))` you can pass `theArray(0)` directly for each of those parameters (OP has no arguments so this is not really relevant here)